# HTML 5 drag and drop and with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

All,

I'm trying to use HTML5 drag and drop and with javascript.  However, I can't get the ability to drop an item into the same location of where the mouse gets released.  Anytime I drop an item into the destinationContainer the X and Y coordinates don't work for top and left styles respectively.

I have included a jsfiddle for reference.  In addition, I have included the snippet code that represents my drop event.

Thanks for any help!

https://jsfiddle.net/mdevera/94vzuo89/2/

```
function drop(event) {

console.log("drop");

event.preventDefault();

var id = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");

if ((id === "item1" || id === "item2") && event.target.className === "destinationContainer" ) {

    var clone = document.getElementById(id).cloneNode(true);

    clone.id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

    /// Style for making item drop in the same mouse location of drop. Does not work.
    //clone.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
    //clone.style.left = event.clientX + "px";


    clone.style.position = "relative";
    event.target.appendChild(clone);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get `X` or `Y` position using `element.offset().top` and `element.offset().left` using jQuery.

Comment: Thank you Pradip, I'm trying to make this happen without jQuery.